# retrofit - charStream and string() cleaning body after use

Tags: android, retrofit

I didn't find nothing about it, but after I called `response.body.charStream()` or `string()`, the next line will receive a empty body. I can see it also doing on evaluate.

***Why this happen and how to handle with it?***

I have a Authenticator using charStream to handle one request, but I need to get the response errorbody to handle another one inside my UseCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found this in okhttp [docs](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/#the-response-body-must-be-closed):
The response body can be consumed only once.

So, I decide to clone the buffer. I found some example inside [HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_3.13.x/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java#L248-L276), a class done by square themselves. And now, its working.

```
private fun cloneBuffer(body:ResponseBody):String{
    val source = body.source()
    source.request(Long.MAX_VALUE)
    val buffer = source.buffer
    return buffer.clone().readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
}
```

I found this [issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2869) about the same thing. And there's a better approach!

```
val responseBody = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE)
```

this won't consume the buffer.